# Why is で used in this sentence 両方セットで差し上げます?

Tags: grammar

So I'm reading a manga and this girl is giving a guy two pieces of paper. She says "正直者ですね。両方セットで差し上げます。” I would think that a を particle would be used here since the set of papers is an object. "I give the set of papers (to you)." What do I give? The set of papers. I'm looking here, https://core6000.neocities.org/dojg/ , at the 4 main uses of で and none of them seem to explain the particle's usage here. Can anyone explain what で is doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because she omitted the part of the sentence. For example if she was giving apple(りんご)...

- りんご**を**セット**で**差し上げます

... is the correct way. "りんご**を**セット**を**" sounds weird.
The example you have shown omitted the part "りんごを".  That's the reason she says "セットで".
In the web site you have shown, I believe で(2) is the closest usage.

By the way, you can also say ...

- りんご**の**セット**を**差し上げます

So just saying "セットを差し上げます" is correct too.

Comment: Yea I was thinking #2 as well would be closest, but the use of papers for giving sounded a bit odd. One thing I've learned though is that literal translations typically do sound weird in English though. Thanks for the response!